# Method in C++ to get the available screen space on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, window, sdl

I'm looking for a way to get the actual available screen space, similar to the Cocoa NSScreen [visibleFrame](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSScreen_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSScreen/visibleFrame) method, but on Linux. That would be the displays resolution minus the menu-bar/dock/title-bar.

I'm using SDL2 for the windowing code, but can't find anything within the library documentation that might help.

[SDL_GetWindowMaximumSize](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetWindowMaximumSize?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryVideo%5Cb%29%7C%28CategoryEnum%29%7C%28CategoryStruct%29%20%22SDL_GetWindowMaximumSize) seems like the closes candidate, but this is returning 0,0 for me.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps the best way will be to retrieve the size of the menubar/dock/titlebar and subtract that from the total desktop size?  Will keep looking though:)

Comment: Ah yeah, that was on the list of options too, but I couldn't find any ways to get those values either!

Answer (score 0):

Use `SDL_GetDesktopDisplayMode()`,( previously SDL_GetVideoInfo() in
 SDL1.2)

https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetDesktopDisplayMode

Comment: For me this just gives the native resolution of the display. Under Ubuntu 13.10 and Gnome.

Comment: @foips Well.. of course. SDL has no knowledge of any system specific gui objects. Nothing prevents you from using that systems api to get that size then use SDL_GetDesktopDisplayMode() and just substract.

Comment: Ah yeah, so I guess my question is how would I use the systems api to get that information?